# Tastypie FormValidation error message

Tags: django, angularjs, tastypie

In my project, I use TastyPies FormValidation for my ModelResource. However, when I try to send invalid data via AJAX PUT request (with AngularJS), like:

```
{ "first_name": "", ... }
```

I get the response:

```
{"customuser": {"first_name": ["[u'This field is required.']"]}}
```

I can't parse the error into my form, because of the square brackets and the unicode prefix inside the string. Any idea how to get rid of that?

**Edit**: Turns out the problem is with the django-angular module. Their NgModelFormMixin causes the bug. Still haven't found the solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out django-angular doesn't play well with TastyPie. After some debugging, I found out that their TupleErrorList didn't correctly render ValidationErrors. Fixed class:

```
from django.forms.utils import ErrorList
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from djangular.forms.angular_base import TupleErrorList

class FixedTupleErrorList(TupleErrorList, ErrorList):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        """
        This method was missing in django-angulars TupleErrorList
        (don't know why they didn't inherit from the default django ErrorList)
        """
        error = self.data[i]
        if isinstance(error, ValidationError):
            return list(error)[0]
        return error # originally, there was force_text here, but it forced unicode prefixes around strings
```